# AngularJs resolving service from controller with ngResource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, ngresource

I have structured my AngularJs application in a way where I have a factory that fetch data from a back-end using ngResource as a dependency. This factory is injected in a Service, and finally this service is injected in a controller.

The problem is that since my Back-end calls take some time, results are not reflected in the controller. I do manage the promise in the service and it does return a result after some time 'cause I'm able to print it in the console, and I really want to avoid this promise handling in the controller, also the $q usage is now deprecated so I want to know if there's a more fancy solution more like Angular(2/4) that exists for AngularJs to resolve this problem.

Thank you

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Angular 2+ uses [ES6 promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). AngularJS uses [$q service promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api) which are integrated with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc. I am sorry you don't like promises, but they are a reality of either framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see another ways to use Promises (with angularjs $q) since it's in the core of AngularJS.

I found the doc explicit enough about this point : [ngResource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource). However, `ngResource` is a wrapper of `$http` which give you a promise. In an other hand, ngResource provide you an easy way to bypass this step with a callback shortcut.

If you want a fancy solution in angularjs, you should stop usage of $resource / $http, and take a look at [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and [async await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) concepts.

Anothers solutions exists but it's some very old school ways to block your main thread.

NB: I'm very curious about the deprecation of `$q` and the fancy ways of `Angular` you quoted.

Comment: Both the fetch API and the async/await constructs use ES6 promises which are not integrated with the AngularJS framework. On the other hand $q service promises are integrated with the AngularJS framework. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

Comment: It makes sense now why they re-wrote the whole framework, I'm reaching other limits also for the factories based on ngResource. Thanks anyway your answer rocks